# How to disable drag and drop on jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables, datatables-1.10

So I'm using jquery datatables along with `colReorder` to setup a table.  This table has a few features, like how you can click a column header, and select a column to switch with.  In order to make this feature work I had to enable `colReorder`.  The only issue is now, all my columns are draggable.  How can I fix this?

Here's what I've tried

- Setting `draggable` to false
- Setting `bsort` to false
- Setting `bsortable` to false

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Also, here's my constructor:

```
        window.table =
        $table.DataTable({
            data: window.apiData['data'],
            /**
            dat
             * Specify which columns we're going to show
             */
            columns: window.columnMapping,
            /**
             * we want to disable showing page numbers, but still limit the number of results
             */
            dom: "t",
            /**
             * let's disable some dynamic custom css
             */
            asStripClasses: [],
            /**
             * let's keep the pages reasonable to prevent scrolling
             */
            pageLength: 8,

            /**
             * this helps with hotswapping columns
             */
            colReorder: true
        });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can overwrite ColReorders event-bindings to the `<th>` elements. Luckily the events is enriched with a namespace so they easily can be tracked down, and it turns out that `ColReorder.mousedown` is responsible for triggering the column dragging. So you can reset the feature by

```
function resetColReorderMD() {
  $('.dataTable thead th').each(function() {
    var md = $._data($(this)[0]).events.mousedown;
    for (var i=0, l=md.length; i<l; i++) {
      if (md[i].namespace == 'ColReorder') {
        md[i].handler = function() {}
      }
    }  
  })
}

$('#example').DataTable({
  colReorder: true,
  initComplete: function() {
    resetColReorderMD()
  }
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/2y4w3v6g/**

Disabling column reordering when using the ColReorder plugin seems rather meaningless. I guess the mentioned "features" are using ColReorder functionality heavily, and this is the real issue, the above should be considered as a not advisable hack.

Comment: In my case I had to replace `$('.dataTable thead th').each(function() {...})` for `$($('#dataTable').DataTable().columns().header()).each(function() {...})`. Thank you.